# How can I use Angular interpolation to insert a dynamic URL into an elements style?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, interpolation

I am trying to use interpolation to generate background images for my element using variables from the ngFor.

Here's what I currently have, which renders perfectly:

```
  <ion-item-group *ngFor="let game of games">
  <ion-card padding style="background: url('./assets/imgs/Body Harvest (USA).png')">
    <h2>{{game.name}}</h2>
  </ion-card>
  </ion-item-group>
```

game object looks like this:

```
  {
    "Id": 30,
    "name": "Body Harvest",
    "genres": "Action/Adventure/3D shooter",
    "date": "30-Sep-98",
    "images": "Body Harvest (USA).png",
    "developer": "DMA Design",
    "publisher": "Midway",
    "description": "A video game released for the Nintendo 64.",
    "players": 1
  },
```

I am looking for a way to inject the URL using something like this:

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let game of games">
<ion-card padding style="background: url('./assets/imgs/{{games.images}}')">
   <h2>{{game.name}}</h2>
</ion-card>
</ion-item-group>
```

I think part of the issue is that 'game.images' is returned with double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [sanitize](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) the url after you receive your data

```
// component.ts
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
    games;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
            res.forEach(item => {
                item.backgroundImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url("./assets/imgs/' + item.images + '")');
            });
        });
    }
}

// component.html
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let game of games">
    <ion-card padding [style.background-image]="game.backgroundImage">
        <h2>{{game.name}}</h2>
    </ion-card>
</ion-item-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the Following

```
<div style="height:200px" [ngStyle]="{background: 'url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/839721704163155970/'+games+')'}">
    Hello
</div>
```

**Component**

```
games = "LI_TRk1z_400x400.jpg";

<div [ngStyle]="{background: 'url(/img/' + image + ')'"></div>
```

[`Working Example`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select)